# function always return true

Tags: c, cs50

I have troubles with writing a function, that checks if a credit card is valid, using Luhn's Algorithm (multiply every other digit by 2, starting with second-to-last; add the sum of the digits than weren't multiplied by 2; if the total's last digit is 0, the number is valid).

When I started to write a code, I checked these lines:

```
long number2 = ((card % x) / y)\*2;
long number1 = ((card % (x/10)) / (y/10));
```

and they seem to work right. When I try to check again now it kind of ignores the following lines:

```
printf("%li", number1);
```

```
printf("%i", sum)
```

And function always returns true. Also, is it okay that I declare variable `digits` two times?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

bool luhns_algorithm (long, int);
int number_of_digits(long);

int main (void)
{
  int digits = 0;//if i remove this then on line 15 appears mistakes
  long card = get_long("credit card: ");

  number_of_digits(card);

  luhns_algorithm(card, digits);//use of undeclared identifier 'digits'; variable 'digits' is uninitilazed when used here

}


int number_of_digits(long card)
{
  int digits = 0;//cant be used in do while loop if undeclared and uninitialized so I need to write it twice
  do
  {
    digits++;
    card = card/10;
  } while(card != 0);

  printf("%i\n", digits);
  return digits;
}


bool luhns_algorithm (long card, int digits)//always valid for some reason
{
   int sum = 0;
   long x = 100;
   long y = 10;
   for (int i = 0; i < digits/2; i++)
   {
     long number2 = (card % x)/y;
     long number1 = (card % (x/10))/(y/10);

     printf("%li\n", number1);//doesn't work
     printf("%li\n", number2);//doesn't work

     sum = sum + number2 + number1;

     printf("%i\n", sum);//doesn't work

     x = x*100;
     y= y*100;
  }

  if((sum/10) == 0)
  {
    printf("VAlID\n");
    return true;
  }
  printf("INVALID\n");
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Why would a variable local to `main()` be visible in other functions?

Comment: ```num_of_digits``` returns a value, but you ignore it.

Comment: ```(int i = 0; i < digits/2; i++)``` will not run because ```i < digits/2``` will never be true.

Comment: ```luhn's_algorithm``` returns a value, but you ignore it as well.

Comment: `function always return true` is debatable because you never check it.

Comment: ```if((sum/10) == 0)
   {
    printf("VAlID\n");
    return true;```------> ```0/10``` produces ```0```.

Comment: I guess you should pass the result of `num_of_digits` as the parameter `digits` of `luhns_algorithm`

Comment: You should understand the difference between parameters and locals. Also, instead of `num_of_digits(card);`, write `digits = num_of_digits(card);`

Comment: @lookingforhelp That is a very nice feature!

Comment: @lookingforhelp,  `long` is not certainly wide enough for this task.  Better to use `long long` and replace `get_long()` with an appropriate function to return a `long long`.

Comment: What does *it kind of ignores the following lines* and *doesn't work* mean? Describe your problem using specifics.

Comment: Depending on the system, `long` may or may not be wide enough for this task, but `long long` will be wide enough.

Answer (score 0):

The result of the function `number_of_digits` is discarded. This means that the `digits` in your `main()` is always zero. You need to store the result into `digits` :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cs50.h>

bool luhns_algorithm (long, int);
int number_of_digits(long);

int main (void)
{
  int digits;
  long card = get_long("credit card: ");

  digits = number_of_digits(card); //FIXED

  luhns_algorithm(card, digits);

}
```

As you noticed, if `digits` is unitialised then an error appearse. Unititialised variables declared inside a function have an unkown value and the compiler will show a warning if you try to use them before assigning a value.

---

> Also, is it okay that I declare variable `digit` two times?

In C, as with most languages, variables have scopes. Every variable is only visible in its own scope and below. Because your two `digits` variables are in different scopes, they are not visible in the other scope. Your `main()` `digits` is totally independant from your `number_of_digits()` `digits`. See [this explanation](https://www.w3schools.in/c-programming/variable-scope) on variable scope for more informations.

Also note that you actually declare it 3 times. A function parameter behaves exaclty like a variable, with the only difference being that it is initialised with the value passed to the parameters when the function was called.